# Obligar a cargar los ficheros js cada vez que se carge la página

Tags: javascript, archivo, cache

Tengo un desarrollo realizado en PHP, y quiero obligar a los navegadores a que cargen el código de los ficheros js y css cada vez que se vea una página.
Tengo puesto en las cabeceras de las páginas lo siguiente:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Last-Modified" content="0">
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, mustrevalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

para obligar a que no use la caché, pero no funciona.

Cada vez que realizo una modificación en un fichero js, tengo que obligar al navegador a limpiar la caché con Ctrl-F5.
¿Existe alguna manera de obligar a que los navegadores no usen la caché, y siempre cargen los ficheros js cada vez que cargue la página?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Podrías probar a añadir a la URL un timestamp o número random para forzar a que se considere una URL distinta y que el navegador crea que no la ha visitado antes. Por ejemplo: `http://my-server/my-script.js?ts=123412341` o `http://my-server/my-stylesheet.css?ts=54352435`

Comment: Cada URL apunta a un *recurso* diferente, así que tienes que hacer que Apache añada las cabeceras HTTP al recurso JS (que alguna forma habrá, aunque no tengo claro como). Otra cuestión es ver porqué necesitas eso, lo suyo sería hacer que el .JS sea estático y que lo que necesite varíar lo pases como parámetros desde el HTML.

Comment: Esas etiquetas _meta_ funcionan solo para el HTML actual (generado por PHP), pero no para elementos enlazados (CSS, JS, imágenes, etc.). En todo caso, es una configuración que debería hacerse en el servidor: [Ejemplo para Apache](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/8620610), o seguir la buena sugerencia de @Sema

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas. Añadir un timestamp a la URL funciona, gracias Sema. Y con todas las respuestas me habeis aclarado mucho el funcionamiento de los metas. Respondiendo a  SJuan76, los ficheros js cambian casi semanalmente por que al proyecto le voy añadiendo más funcionalidades, y no me gustaba lo de dar Ctrl-F5 cada vez que hacía una modificación. Lo dicho, muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes modificar tu `.htaccess` para prevenir el caché, de la siguiente manera:

```
# DISABLE CACHING
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(css|flv|gif|htm|html|ico|jpe|jpeg|jpg|js|mp3|mp4|png|pdf|swf|txt)$">
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive Off
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        FileETag None
        Header unset ETag
        Header unset Pragma
        Header unset Cache-Control
        Header unset Last-Modified
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Expires "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Esto forzará al navegador a NO guardar en el caché todos los archivos con extensión:

- .css
- .flv
- .gif
- .htm, .html
- .ico, .jpe, .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .pdf
- .js
- .mp3, .mp4, .swf
- .txt

Las etiquetas que pusiste a tu archivo solo afectarán a el mismo, mas no a los otros archivos del sitio.

Comment: Muchas gracias anythingg por tu ayuda. El hosting me permite modificar el .htaccess y esta opción es la más rápida.